# Delete multiple repositories at once in Atlassian Stash

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I have a project with roughly 30 repositories inside my stash. I fiddled around with them a bit and now I want to reset everything and re-import them. As far as I could see, there is no way to "clean" a repository in Stash, so I decided to just delete them and create them again. Since there are a bunch of repositories, and this is probably not the last time I'm going to do this, I would be really thankful for a way to delete/create multiple repositories at once, since I would need a considerable amount of time to do this manually via the frontend. Does anyone know, if that is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stash developer here. I haven't seen a plugin on Marketplace that would do that. Would a simple bash script that uses our [REST api](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/latest/stash-rest.html#idp1181904) work for you?

```
for path in 'projectA/repos/repoA' 'myprojectB/repos/myrepoB' 'somethingC/repos/somethingC'; do curl -X DELETE --user username:password http://host:port/rest/api/1.0/projects/$path; done
```

Or something like that

Comment: Didn't see your answer until just now. I already wrote a perl-script using the REST API :) Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Via a linux machine that has access to your stash/bitbucket host I came up with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
USER='someUser'
PASS='secretPassWord'

sudo apt-get -qq install jq curl
TMP=/tmp/PROJECTS.TO.DELETE.$RANDOM

# Get a list of all Projects
curl -k -s --user $USER:$PASS "https://stashHost/rest/api/1.0/projects/?limit=10000" | jq -r ".values[].key" | sort >$TMP

# Allow an opertunity to remove some projects from this deletion process
nano $TMP

# Loop through the remaining projects listed in the $TMP file and remove all repo's and projects.
for P in $(cat $TMP); do
        echo "Project: $P"
        for R in $(curl -k -s --user $USER:$PASS "https://stashHost/rest/api/1.0/projects/$P/repos?limit=10000" | jq -r ".values[].slug" | sort);
        do
                # Delete the repository
                OUTPUT=`curl -k -s -X DELETE --user $USER:$PASS "https://stashHost/rest/api/1.0/projects/$P/repos/$R" | jq -r ".message"`
                printf "Deleting: %10s\t%40s\t%s\n" $P $R "$OUTPUT"
        done;
        # Delete the empty project (with no remaining repos)
        curl -k -s -X DELETE --user $USER:$PASS "https://stashHost/rest/api/1.0/projects/$P";
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like a PHP like me, and wand to use to interact with Bitbucket.
Also, this code example work with API V2.

1. Create the app password with at least read/delete permissions for Repositories [here](https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/), save the app password.
2. Get your Bitbucket user name [here](https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/)
3. Add composer dependencies `composer require mashape/unirest-php symfony/var-dumper`.
4. Create file with this PHP code:

```
$autoloader = require_once 'autoload.php';
$encoded = base64_encode('<user name>:<app password>');
$headers = [
  'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $encoded,
];
// Get the list of repositories.
$workspace = 'dstorozhuk';
$response = Unirest\Request::get(
  'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/' . $workspace,
  $headers
); 
$repos = [];
foreach ($response->body->values as $item) {
  $repos[] = $item->slug;
}
var_export($repos);
// Copy  the the provided array as PHP variable yo your code
```

Then in another file, or in the same file you can call the enpoint to delete the repos:

```
$slugs = ['repo1', 'repo2'];
foreach ($slugs as $slug) {
  $response = Unirest\Request::delete(
    'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/' . $workspace . '/' . $slug,
    $headers
  );
  dump($response);
}
```